# Cost of inciting a revolt

Tags: freeciv

What is the formula that determines the cost of inciting a revolt using diplomats/spies? I know that for a capital it is 1000000 gp. I could only find a formula for the costs of bribing/sabotaging units on the [FreeCiv Wikia](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Diplomatic_actions), but not for cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, it depends on the ruleset. A section of the 'classic' game.ruleset is below.

```
[incite_cost]
; city_incite_cost = total_factor * (city_size) * (base_incite_cost
;                      + (units_cost) * unit_factor
;                      + (improvements_cost) * improvement_factor)
;                    / ((distance to capital) * 100)
; See city_incite_cost() for more details
base_incite_cost = 1000
improvement_factor = 1
unit_factor = 2
total_factor = 100
```

This formula is not actually used (it is a comment) but the values are. It is basically correct but is missing many modifiers and a distance cap I will show below.

The long answer is found mostly in server\cityturn.c, but depends on many, many files. (You can download the uncompiled version of freeciv for these, below is just part of server\cityturn.c)

```
int city_incite_cost(struct player *pplayer, struct city *pcity)
{
  struct city *capital;
  int dist, size;
  double cost; /* Intermediate values can get very large */

  if (get_city_bonus(pcity, EFT_NO_INCITE) > 0) {
    return INCITE_IMPOSSIBLE_COST;
  }

  /* Gold factor */
  cost = city_owner(pcity)->economic.gold + game.server.base_incite_cost;

  unit_list_iterate(pcity->tile->units, punit) {
    cost += (unit_build_shield_cost(punit)
         * game.server.incite_unit_factor);
  } unit_list_iterate_end;

  /* Buildings */
  city_built_iterate(pcity, pimprove) {
    cost += impr_build_shield_cost(pimprove)
            * game.server.incite_improvement_factor;
  } city_built_iterate_end;

  /* Stability bonuses */
  if (!city_unhappy(pcity)) {
    cost *= 2;
  }
  if (city_celebrating(pcity)) {
    cost *= 2;
  }

  /* City is empty */
  if (unit_list_size(pcity->tile->units) == 0) {
    cost /= 2;
  }

  /* Buy back is cheap, conquered cities are also cheap */
  if (!game.info.citizen_nationality) {
    if (city_owner(pcity) != pcity->original) {
      if (pplayer == pcity->original) {
        cost /= 2;            /* buy back: 50% price reduction */
      } else {
        cost = cost * 2 / 3;  /* buy conquered: 33% price reduction */
      }
    }
  }

  /* Distance from capital */
  capital = player_capital(city_owner(pcity));
  if (capital) {
    int tmp = map_distance(capital->tile, pcity->tile);
    dist = MIN(32, tmp);
  } else {
    /* No capital? Take max penalty! */
    dist = 32;
  }

  size = MAX(1, city_size_get(pcity)
                + pcity->feel[CITIZEN_HAPPY][FEELING_FINAL]
                - pcity->feel[CITIZEN_UNHAPPY][FEELING_FINAL]
                - pcity->feel[CITIZEN_ANGRY][FEELING_FINAL] * 3);
  cost *= size;
  cost *= game.server.incite_total_factor;
  cost = cost / (dist + 3);

  if (game.info.citizen_nationality) {
    int cost_per_citizen = cost / pcity->size;
    int natives = citizens_nation_get(pcity, city_owner(pcity)->slot);
    int tgt_cit = citizens_nation_get(pcity, pplayer->slot);
    int third_party = pcity->size - natives - tgt_cit;

    cost = cost_per_citizen * (natives + 0.7 * third_party + 0.5 * tgt_cit); 
  }

  cost += (cost * get_city_bonus(pcity, EFT_INCITE_COST_PCT)) / 100;
  cost /= 100;

  if (cost >= INCITE_IMPOSSIBLE_COST) {
    return INCITE_IMPOSSIBLE_COST;
  } else {
    return cost;
  }
}
```

To summarize: If the city is not naturally impossible to bribe,

-Add the target player's gold to ruleset base_incite_cost (default 1000)

-Add (ruleset unit_factor (default 2) times total shield cost of units in city)

-Add (ruleset improvement_factor (default 1) times total shield cost of improvements (buildings) in city)

(This total is now multiplied/divided by other modifiers)

-Multiply by 2 if not unhappy

-Multiply by 2 if celebrating

-Divide by 2 if there are no units in the city

-Divide by 2 if it was originally your city

-Multiply by 2/3 if it is not originally you or the current owner's city

-Multiply by (city size + happy citizens - unhappy citizens - (3*angry citizens)) *Note this will not go below 1 due to max

-Multiply by ruleset total_factor (default 100)

-Divide by (distance from capital (capped at 32) plus 3)

-If nationality enabled (in cities.ruleset), Multiply by (0.5*fraction of citizens your nationality + 1*fraction of citizens owner's nationality + 0.7*fraction of citizens other nationality)

-Multiply by ( (a special percentage increase, normally only from courthouses Incite_Cost_Pct (default 300), divided by 100)+1 )

-Divide by 100

Misc. Notes/references

Nationality in cities.ruleset

```
[citizen]
nationality   = TRUE            ; account for the nationality of the citizens
```

Incite_Cost_Pct in effects.ruleset

```
[effect_courthouse_3]
type    = "Incite_Cost_Pct"
value   = 300
```

As an aside, the 1000000 value is defined as the INCITE_IMPOSSIBLE_COST, and will appear for cities containing a palace (capitals), or in a democracy.

From common\city.h

```
#define INCITE_IMPOSSIBLE_COST (1000 * 1000 * 1000)
```